# Changes on my website are not reflected quickly

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, caching

Cache issue or something else I am failing to understand.

Since last two weeks I am facing a bizarre condition not only on my website but also my API written for mobile app.

The problem is changes I am making on my website are not reflected quickly. It's taking a lot of time, same goes for my mobile API.

For example: If I delete any item from my app that item is deleted from my database but it's still showing in my item list. After refreshing 100's of time it stop showing.

I made my web app and API using codeigniter 3 and I am hosting my website on bluehost server.

Comment: Yes that sounds like a caching issue. Good caching systems have a sort of onion quality to them. Lots of layers. Unfortunately that makes it quite hard to debug. Have you explicitly enabled any caching?

Comment: Nope I haven't enabled any cache but Yes from blue host server I disabled(which was enabled from starting) the cache then it's start working fine but then I am facing another problem the problem is  my website becomes damn slow..any solution for that?

Comment: By blue host caching do you mean php opcache? If so, that's perfectly safe. I would check to see if you are getting Expires headers set in the future for your view's responses. If you are, it's http caching by your browser or intermediate proxy if you have one.

Comment: By bluehost caching I mean bluehost server caching..the same code is working fine on my company server but it's giving all this issue on bluehost server so I am not getting what exactly the problem is

Comment: I see from your other question that you tried echo-ing something, and this was cached in the output even after removing the echo from the php. Your first step should be to reproduce the settings that cause the caching issue, but on somewhere that isn't production. In this safe environment with caching, try `echo time();` and see if the number increases on each request.

Comment: OK will try to do that and tell you what result I get

Comment: As u told i echo time on my website but from last twenty minutes its showing the same time so i think its getting cached and i am sure after few minutes its gonna change and its happening after i enabled cached on my website

Comment: OK so you need to figure out what the bluehost caching option does, reproduce it locally and fix the issue. You can probably influence how long things are cached for with a header in your php code for views `header('Expires: ' . gmdate('r', strtotime('+1 minute', gmmktime()));`. Caching is a balancing act between out of date pages and slow websites. Another method would be to invalidate the cache of the view when things are updated, but that requires knowing what's going on currently.